# 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683) error message using jquery

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm having an issue with the 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683) error and I could use some help. I already added the  "noImplicitAny": false
to the tsconfig.json file. This is what i'm trying to do
https://codepen.io/daveredfern/pen/zBGBJV
Please and thank you!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
  
@Component({
  selector: 'app-color-change',
  templateUrl: './color-change.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./color-change.component.scss']
})
export class ColorChangeComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
  
      // selectors
      var $window = $(window),
          $body = $('body'),
          $panel = $('.panel');
      
      // Change 33% earlier than scroll position so colour is there when you arrive.
      var scroll = $window.scrollTop() + ($window.height() / 3);
     
      $panel.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        
        // if position is within range of this panel.
        // So position of (position of top of div <= scroll position) && (position of bottom of div > scroll position).
        // Remember we set the scroll to 33% earlier in scroll var.
        if ($this.position().top <= scroll && $this.position().top + $this.height() > scroll) {
              
          // Remove all classes on body with color-
          $body.removeClass(function (index, css) {
            return (css.match (/(^|\s)color-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
          });
           
          // Add class of currently active div
          $body.addClass('color-' + $(this).data('color'));
        }
      });    
      
    }).scroll();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see several possible options, for example

1. tsconfig - `noImplicitThis`
2. `$panel.each(function (this: HTMLButtonElement) { var $this = $(this); })`
3. use types

`npm i --save-dev @types/jquery`

`import * as $ from 'jquery';`

4. specify function parameters without using "this"